# Inserting array values inside an auto complete list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently making an auto-complete form. Right now, the values of suggestions are from inside a JavaScript list:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#textarea').textext({
    plugins : 'autocomplete suggestions tags filter',

    suggestions: [
        'Basic',
        'Cobol',
        'Go'
    ]
});
```

I am using a function to get my list of names from a database:

```
    $users->selectFirstnameSurname();
    $userQueryResult = $users->queryResult;
    $listOfNames = $users->listOfNames;
```

I am taking the values by appending firstname and lastname from the database, like this:

```
    public function selectFirstnameSurname() {
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `username`");
    $listOfNames[] = '';

    try{
        $query->execute();
        foreach ($query as $row) {
                array_push ($listOfNames, $row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname']);
            }
        $this->queryResult = $query->fetch();
        $this->listOfNames = $listOfNames;

        } catch(PDOException $e){

            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is get the values of array `$listOfNames` and replace the suggestions from the script.

Comment: just use a default jquery autocomplete plugin then all you have to do is create a php page that returns a json of your array

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a way to deliver the dataset so that your javascript code can access it. If your dataset is static and JS does the filtering, you could just statically dump them as a JS Object (JSON) like

```
[
  { 
   "id": 1,
   "label": "user name"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "other user"
  }
]
```

The exact format of the JSON of course depends on your autocomplete implementation.

Or to make it more dynamic (good idea if you have a big dataset) you could make a simple API  called over AJAX to fetch the data. If you need more detail, you can refer a tutorial like http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step

Comment: Actually my script completes more values, not just one. What I am trying to do is make an autocompletion way of multiple values just like on stackoverflow when you select the tags and you select PHP, JQUERY and JAVASCRIPT for instance. Everything works just fine, my only problem is getting it to suggest stuff based on all my users from the database, and I cannot write it manually since there will be like 500+ and many will leave and arrive meanwhile. I read that JSON is the way of doing it but I'm not sure how. What I want to do is make it show firstname+lastname but retain the id or username.

Comment: You need to make an API to your server, that provides that data. The JS makes a query to the URL exposed by the server (something like "/autocomplete?search=firstname") that returns only the relevant results (the ones that match given search parameter) as JSON. Check out the tutorial that I linked, it presents the concepts you need to understand to make this work. If there are things that you don't understand, you'll find clear points to study.